# Getting All Values from a Criteria - Excel / GS

Tags: excel, google-sheets, multiple-columns, vlookup, distinct-values

I'm having an issue that I can't get a formula to work on google sheets:

[image]

I have 2 Columns, one saying **Cliente** and the other **Artigo**. On the right side, I have one column getting unique values from **"Cliente"**, named **"Cliente Unico"**.

What I want is to get on the Column named **Teste1** and **Teste2** all the values from the "Artigo" Column that has on the left the same name as the column name "Teste1 or Teste2".

Any idea how to make this? I tried vlookup but I get the same value all the time.

I don't mind if you help me using Excel, I will adapt it to Google Sheets.

Thanks.

### Edit:

What I want to do is this:

[image]

Of course, this was manually inserted, I want to do this with formulas.

Comment: `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTER()` for example? Or, if in GS, use `QUERY()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant do with that formulas. What I want is to get the all that data that has Teste1 or Teste2 on the left table to the right table.

Comment: What does *"I can't do that with formulas"* mean? What are you refering too? There is no sample desired output so the above suggestion seems perfectly fit.

Comment: @JvdV, see the image that I inserted, that is what I need to do.

Comment: So use `FILTER()` and forget I mentioned `TEXTJOIN()`. I don't get what you mean with "You can't do that".

Comment: Ah Okay, you are right, I was confused with the TEXTJOIN(). It's done and its quite easy in fact. I was making a stom in the cup. Thanks a lot @JvdV

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output